# How generated WebAssembly module looks with a lot of dynamic data

Tags: webassembly

Say a WebAssembly module (`wat` format) will be generated with a lot of data. Once the program starts running, the data will be dynamically changed and altered at runtime. Not quite sure I understand where to put that data in the generated WebAssembly module.

I am trying to accomplish (in WebAssembly) what this JavaScript is demonstrating:

```
var data = [
  100.1, 100.2, 200.1, 200.2,
  300.12, 300.123, ...
]
```

And I will eventually do stuff like:

```
var subset = data.slice(2, 4)
storeSubset(subset)
data[5] = 500.3
subset[2] = 600
```

...but in WebAssembly not JavaScript, where `data` and `subset` are local variables to some function; they aren't global variables. Although possibly there is one global dataset if that is necessary.

Wondering where to place the data in the generated module. So the program will have this data *built into it* from the start. Basically, there is some initialization data that will be dynamically modified at runtime.

This is what I'm trying to accomplish in pseudocode:

```
(module
  (load float16 memorylocation, 200.1)
  (load float16 memorylocation, 200.2)
  ... for every piece of data
)
```

Not sure (a) if it should be done similar to that (one piece at a time), or (b) it can be done in bulk somehow. Like this:

```
(module
  (static memorylocation, 0101010110101...) ;; the bytes of all the `data`
  (block (loop ...)) ;; loop through it and do `(load ...)` for each,
  ;; not sure if that would be better / performance / etc.
  ...
)
```

Load all the bytes in one spot and loop through them?

Or maybe there is a more standard sort of `.data` feature like assembly (though I'm not sure if that is appropriate for *dynamic* data).

```
(module
  (data float16 memorylocation, 200.1)
  (data float16 memorylocation, 200.2)
  ...
)
```

I understand how to do *functions* in WebAssembly so far, just not how to deal with initialization data, because it seems like it would generate a *lot* of WebAssembly, and not sure what kind of WebAssembly that should be.

Comment: What are you using to generate your code? Presumably it's C++ code?

Comment: Sure lets say it's C++. But I would like to know how the `wat` looks.

Answer (score 2):

WebAssembly binaries contain a [data segment](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/BinaryEncoding.md#data-section) section which is copied into the memory before `start` is invoked and before the instance starts running.

A C++ compiler would put the equivalent of `.rodata` and any other static initialization for `.data` in there. This is then modifiable at runtime.